# Should I try to implement MVVM pattern in MacRuby, or there is another pattern which suits better?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, mvvm, macruby

I am creating a small GUI application with MacRuby, and since I am from .NET world (WPF) I want to use MVVM pattern in my app. But I am not sure if it is OK ti walk MVVM way with Ruby, because probably there can be another more suitable way in MacRuby ecosystem.
So should I use MVVM, or anything else to create lean concern separated classes?

Answer (score 0):

With the Cocoa framework, the [MVC design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) is central to a good design.

Here is a discussion on the [differences between MVC and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm).