# Is this the right way to implement MVVM in PHP?

Tags: php, mvvm

I heard about MVVM a couple of days ago, I searched about it and read a few articles, but I'm really confused now and I don't know what ViewModel in Model-View-ViewModel really is.

1. Is following sample a right way to implement MVVM in PHP?
2. Where should I process form request?

---

**View:** View is a simple (logic-less) output template, like a Mustache template:

```
Hi {{name}}!
```

---

**Model:** Saves and retrieves raw data. Like a user class:

```
class user
{
    public function __construct($username){...};

    public function set_firstname($firstname){...};
    public function get_firstname(){...};

    public function set_lastname($lastname){...};
    public function get_lastname(){...};
}
```

---

**ViewModel:** Processes Model's raw data and sends results to View

```
class ViewModel
{
    public function request_showUserPage()
    {
        $user      = new user('sample@example.com');

        $firstname = $user->firstname;
        $lastname  = $user->lastname;

        $name = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;

        $variables = 
            [
                'name' => $name
            ]

        $Mustache = new Mustache_Engine
        echo $Mustache->render('{{name}}', $variables);
    }
}
```

So, output will be:

`Hi John Smith!`

Comment: You might want to read this blog on MVC http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/a-beginners-guide-to-mvc-for-web.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm