# difference between MVC and MVVM models

Tags: model-view-controller

I have referred a number of books and websites but did not clearly got the difference between MVC (model view controller) and MVVM (model view viewmodel). Please, can someone explain clearly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between MVC and MVVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm)

Comment: and [What are the differences and similarities between MVC and MVVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151831/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-mvc-and-mvvm?lq=1)