# What is the difference between active MVC and MVVM and how do you implement active MVC in Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture

I know a similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm) but I am confused on below points

- How to implement active MVC in asp.net MVC?
- If active MVC is used
  with observer pattern or SignalR then what are the difference between
  MVVM and active MVC?

Comment: Why down voting? would you like to comment?

Comment: it is not the logic for down vote if you are unable to answer the question other wise put a comment along with your down vote.