# Xamarin Access ViewModel Properties

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, mvvm, mvvmcross

Is it possible to access a property which is located in a ViewModel from outside of the ViewModel? I'm running a check (TriggerAction) on one of my entries, and I need to access a property (a double) from my ViewModel, which I need to use to limit my numeric entry. I was able to come up with a way to actually limit my entry to not go above a certain number, but I need it to not go above this specific number from my ViewModel.

Comment: of course.  A VM is just a class.  If you have an instance of a class, you can access it's public properties.

Comment: refer to my post on another question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285766/view-to-different-view-model-binding-in-xamarin-forms/64286130#64286130

Comment: Sure, you can access ViewModel properties, share us some relevant code please.