# Pass diffrent viewmodel with other viewmodel to show page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have question. I use to use `Send` to pass the `viewmodel` to show other `page` as shown below:

```
public class UsersViewModel : IUsersViewModel 
{
  void ShowCars()
  {
      MessagingCenter.Send<IUsersViewModel>(this, "ShowCarsViewPage");
  }
}
```

As you see above, i use this. Now i have situation that i need to pass diffrent `viewmoodel` inside `UsersViewModel`. I want to add `ShowBuildings` inside `UsersViewModel`. The problem is as it's diffrent `viewmodel` to be passed i cannot use `this` which leds me to use `new` keyword and pass all dependencies. How can i overcome that?

```
  void ShowBuildings()
  {
      MessagingCenter.Send<IBuildingsViewModel>(new Buildings(new DataStorage()), "ShowBuildingsViewPage");
  }
```

My first thought is to pass that `view model` i need to use into `UsersViewModel's` `ctor` but not sure if this is right way like to insert another `view model` into other `view model`?:

```
public class UsersViewModel : IUsersViewModel 
{
     private readonly IBuildingsViewModel _buildingviewmodel;
     
     UsersViewMode(IBuildingsViewModel buildingviewmodel)
     {
          _buildingviewmodel = buildingviewmodel;     
     }

     //So then:
     void ShowBuildings()
      {
          MessagingCenter.Send<IBuildingsViewModel>(_buildingviewmodel, "ShowBuildingsViewPage");
      }
}
```

Comment: you first need to use singleton , check this , then you can use any instance of any viewmodel anytime , you dont even need to send it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285766/view-to-different-view-model-binding-in-xamarin-forms/64286130#64286130

Answer (score 0):

Check [xamarin publisher documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center#publish-a-message). The third parameter is the payload data that is being sent.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", "John");
```

Tip: Try to bundle multiple ViewModels with an interface and pass that. In this way you will not be tied to specific ViewModels interfaces.

```
interface IBuildingCollection : IEnumerable<Building>
{
}

class ViewModel1 : IBuildingsViewModel, IBuildingCollection
{
}

class ViewModel2 : IBuildingsViewModel, IBuildingCollection
{
}

class UsersViewModel : IUsersViewModel
{
    void ShowBuildings(IBuildingCollection collection)
    {
      MessagingCenter.Send<IUsersViewModel, IBuildingCollection>(this, "ShowBuildingsViewPage", collection);
    }
}

class ReceiverViewModel : IReceiverViewModel 
{
   public ReceiverViewModel() 
   {
       MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IUsersViewModel, IBuildingCollection>(this, "ShowBuildingsViewPage", myDelegate);
   }
   
   public void myDelegate(IBuildingCollection buildings) 
   {
       // Do something with buildings
   }
}
```

Comment: What about my solution at the bottom of my post? Can i just pass (of course using interface and not real object) other vide model into another view model?

Comment: That is not a valid solution. You are switching the sender = 'this' with another object, which is bad because you broken the pub-sub pattern.