# Is React MVVM framework?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a web application using React.js. When I went to the interview, I found that I couldn't explain the MVVM concept very well. At that time, I said, for example, in a component, M is state in react, V is jsx, and MV is an event operation to change state. So I said MVVM is reflected in react like this, and later they told me it wasn't MVVM. Don't say my question is so simple. I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't React considered MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729411/why-isnt-react-considered-mvc)

Comment: Please see this answer. It explains ReactJS and MVVM well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506440/mvvm-architectural-pattern-for-a-reactjs-application

Comment: Please see:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506440/mvvm-architectural-pattern-for-a-reactjs-application). It explains ReactJS and MVVM pattern well.

Answer (score 3):

When interviewer asked me about ReactJS I said that ReactJS is a view library.

Answer (score 0):

Vue 3 (MVVM):

```css
      Proxy       Update
  Model → ViewModel → View
  Model ← ViewModel ← View
      Update      Event
```

React:

```css
     setState     Update
  Model → ViewModel → View
  Model ← ViewModel ← View
      Update      Event
```

The difference is only how the frameworks notify Model changes to the ViewModel.