# ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET Core MVC with Angular as frontend?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create a website / web application with .NET Core in the backend and Angular as frontend. I am still in the planning phase and one thing I don't come to understand is if one would use `ASP.NET Core` or `ASP.NET Core MVC` in the backend. Which one of them is typically used any why?

The reason I am asking this is that to my knowledge I don't use `MVC` with Angular (but instead I use `MVVM`). Therefore I would assume I don't need `ASP.NET CORE MVC`, but there are books like [Essential Angular for ASP.NET Core MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484229150) (emphasis on `MVC`), so I am wondering how that all fits together.

Comment: you should create web API use ASP.NET Core, and use API in angular using HttpClient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why there are books with MVC in the title? Does this maybe have historic reasons?

Comment: Questions like this is off topic at SO. That said, here's a good read how MVC compare to MVVM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm

Comment: They combine MVC and angular it same with you can combine MVC and Web API in one solution

Answer (score -1):

So, I think I figured it out. The way to go is to create a Web API and then use the HttpClient in Angular (as commented by Hien). Documentation e.g. at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2 shows that while creating the Web API some things are borrowed from the ASP.NET Core MVC namespaces. Guess that's there the MVC is coming from. Parts from it are used, just not the complete thing.