# What is the difference between .xaml.cs and ViewModels/ViewModel.cs?

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have been following this tutorial on MVVM pattern using caliburn micro

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laPFq3Fhs8k

What is the difference between .xaml.cs and ViewModels/ViewModel.cs ?

I see we put our code for the shellview in ShellViewModel.cs, but when I, for example,  choose an event handler for a Button, visual studio takes me to .xaml.cs and not to the ViewModels/ViewModel.

Do I have to stick to one or each file has a different role/responsibility? ( considering that I want my code to still be following MVVM pattern )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files ending in `.xaml.cs` are what is called the View's "code-behind". Anything inside this file is tightly coupled with the View.

If you want to follow the MVVM pattern, you will code almost all of the interaction of the UI with your Models (example: click of a button change some data or get some data from the database) on the ViewModels (`.cs files`), which are independent from the Views.

The only link between the View and the ViewModel is that the ViewModel is the `DataContext` of the View. In other words, the View knows about the ViewModel, but that ViewModel does not know anything about the View.

Event Handlers are not generally used in a MVVM world. You need to use Commands. But that is a whole other question/answer.

The important thing to keep in mind is that MVVM comes to address, mainly, two things: the Separation of Concerns (UI vs UI Logic) and Testability of your software.

Comment: marked this as the accepted answer because to me this said it all `In other words, the View knows about the ViewModel, but that ViewModel does not know anything about the View.`

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by suggesting that you learn the basics of the UI framework you're using (WPF, etc.) before adding an additional framework on top of it. I've seen that this only makes the learning curve steeper.

With that said, the .xaml.cs file is what is commonly referred to as the *code behind*. This is the code that "controls", so to speak, the UI. You'll note, for example, that these are all "partial" classes because there's going to be some auto-generated code when you compile that does view-specific things like bindings, etc.. **The xaml.cs file should be used sparingly and only when you need to know or operate on specifics of the View itself.**

With MVVM, you'll often see code behind classes that are almost completely empty, with just a constructor present. The logic in these cases is moved to a "View Model" class which provides a link between the View and the Model (take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm) for a more thorough description). **You should bind to objects in the View Model, and use it as the data context for your view. It contains all the logic to define how the view effects your model.**

So - applying this to event handlers... An event must live in the code-behind, because you can't explicitly bind to one in your VM. You could easily call the function you want by accessing the ViewModel right inside that event handler, and there's nothing particularly egregious about this approach. That said, there is another concept called a Command that will live in the View Model itself; a command, as opposed to an event handler, is a Property, so you can bind to that in your .xaml file using

```
...Command="{Binding FunctionNameHere}"...
```

It also has nice features like being able to define when the command is valid (so you can disable your button automatically when, for example, the form is missing a required field).